# How to compile and finetune bert model from Huggingface's transformers?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I'm switching to Pytorch 2.0.1 and want to compile the model for training times improvement. There are two approaches for model compilation - using torch API and transformers API, and neither of them works as expected.

### Transformers API

Training becomes waaaay slower (10-30 times, A10G GPU). Maybe it's because of dynamic input shapes (which kinda should be padded anyway)

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_id, num_labels=num_labels, label2id=label2id, id2label=id2label
)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./temp",
    per_device_train_batch_size=128,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=128,
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    torch_compile=True,
    optim="adamw_torch_fused",
    logging_steps=1,
    logging_strategy="steps",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=2,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="f1",
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

### Pytorch API

It should have solved the dynamic input size issue, but it refuses to run at all and throws an error

```py
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
    model_id, num_labels=num_labels, label2id=label2id, id2label=id2label
)
model = torch.compile(model, dynamic=True, fullgraph=True)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./temp",
    per_device_train_batch_size=128,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=128,
    learning_rate=5e-5,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    optim="adamw_torch_fused",
    logging_steps=1,
    logging_strategy="steps",
    evaluation_strategy="epoch",
    save_strategy="epoch",
    save_total_limit=2,
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="f1",
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=dataset["train"],
    eval_dataset=dataset["test"],
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)

trainer.train()
```

Here is the error

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer_pt_utils.py in get_model_param_count(model, trainable_only)
   1051             return p.numel()
   1052 
-> 1053     return sum(numel(p) for p in model.parameters() if not trainable_only or p.requires_grad)
   1054 
   1055 

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'parameters'
```

Here is corresponding [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VnPcPyQ0Jg55Zn0x8pNJq-tQRX2IwIYR?usp=sharing)

How can I make pytorch API work?

Comment: I ran the code in colab and input shapes weren't dynamic. and on T4 gpu there was close to 20% decrease in speed probably because t4 is not good for this purpose. perhaps you are referring to 30 times decrease because of the initial compile time that seems too long when you only train few samples?
as for pytorch API, I couldn't figure out the source of the issue.

Comment: yeah, so if you remove the `padding` from the tokenizer call - the inputs become dynamic, and the model gets recompiled after each batch or so

Comment: apparently in huggingface the torch_compile is handled by accelerate library and the default value for dynamic is False so it naturally it recompiles for every batch size. I don't know much about accelerate but it seems that it's possible to use the arg to make it dynamic with dynamo_use_dynamic. the documentation is very scarce for this and it's confusing.